# label changes position after moving window pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this window where the mainlayout is a `QVBoxlayout` with nested `QHBoxlayout`

On top a have set two labels, for some reasons
`pressen_label = qtw.QLabel("Choose  A")` label is changing its position after the window is moved or resized with the mouse.

before moving/change size of the window with mouse

[image]

after moving the window

[image]

How can I lock the position of the label so its not moving?

```
pressen_label = qtw.QLabel("Choose  A")
quality_label = qtw.QLabel("Choose  B")
hblayout_labelcombo = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
hblayout_labelcombo.addWidget(pressen_label)
hblayout_labelcombo.addStretch(1)
hblayout_labelcombo.addWidget(quality_label)
hblayout_labelcombo.addStretch(10)
hblayout_labelcombo.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignTop)
```

full code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
template interface

"""


import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class SwellingwindowParent(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # your code will go here


        # position
        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = qtw.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveTop(100)

        # size
        self.resize(1400, 910)
        # frame title
        self.setWindowTitle("Parent Window")

        # widgets

        # combobox label and layout
        pressen_label = qtw.QLabel("Choose  A")
        quality_label = qtw.QLabel("Choose  B")
        hblayout_labelcombo = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        hblayout_labelcombo.addWidget(pressen_label)
        hblayout_labelcombo.addStretch(1)
        hblayout_labelcombo.addWidget(quality_label)
        hblayout_labelcombo.addStretch(10)
        hblayout_labelcombo.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignTop)

        # combobox widget and layout
        comobox_selectpressen = qtw.QComboBox()
        comobox_selectpressen.setFixedWidth(130)
        comobox_selectquality = qtw.QComboBox()
        comobox_selectquality.setFixedWidth(130)
        hblayout_widgetcombobox = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        hblayout_widgetcombobox.addWidget(comobox_selectpressen)
        hblayout_widgetcombobox.addStretch(1)
        hblayout_widgetcombobox.addWidget(comobox_selectquality)
        hblayout_widgetcombobox.addStretch(30)
        hblayout_widgetcombobox.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignTop)

        # mss
        heading_messschieber = qtw.QLabel("Mss stuff")
        button_messschiber = qtw.QPushButton("mss start")
        # M
        messchiber_heading = qtw.QLabel("want to start msss ?")
        hblayout_labelmsslayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        hblayout_labelmsslayout.addWidget(messchiber_heading)
        hblayout_labelmsslayout.addStretch(2)
        hblayout_labelmsslayout.addWidget(quality_label)
        hblayout_labelmsslayout.addStretch(30)

        msss_messuungstartenbutton = qtw.QPushButton("msss start")
        hblayout_mssbuttonlayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        hblayout_mssbuttonlayout.addWidget(msss_messuungstartenbutton)
        hblayout_mssbuttonlayout.addStretch(2)
        hblayout_mssbuttonlayout.addWidget(quality_label)
        hblayout_mssbuttonlayout.addStretch(30)

        # spacer  set custum vertical space
        verticalSpacer1 = qtw.QSpacerItem(10, 10, qtw.QSizePolicy.Minimum, vPolicy=qtw.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        verticalSpacer2 = qtw.QSpacerItem(10, 5, qtw.QSizePolicy.Minimum, vPolicy=qtw.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        verticalSpacer3 = qtw.QSpacerItem(10, 50, qtw.QSizePolicy.Minimum, vPolicy=qtw.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        verticalSpacer4 = qtw.QSpacerItem(3, 1, vPolicy=qtw.QSizePolicy.Fixed)


        # main layout
        mainlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        mainlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignTop) # needed for custom spacers
        mainlayout.addSpacerItem(verticalSpacer1)
        mainlayout.addLayout(hblayout_labelcombo)
        mainlayout.addSpacerItem(verticalSpacer2)
        mainlayout.addLayout(hblayout_widgetcombobox)
        mainlayout.addSpacerItem(verticalSpacer3)

        mainlayout.addLayout(hblayout_labelmsslayout)
        mainlayout.addLayout(hblayout_mssbuttonlayout)
        # mainlayout.addSpacerItem(verticalSpacer1)


        self.setLayout(mainlayout)

        # your code ends here
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SwellingwindowParent()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you have an XY problem. Could you indicate which is the structure you want to obtain

Comment: @eyllanesc this structure I want to obtain, after moving the window up/down the right label switches it position somehow [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/754ngrm)

Comment: Your image does not help. Create an image of the structure you want to obtain using all the elements: QLabel, QPushButton, QComboBox, etc to understand what you want. If you don't, I won't be able to help you, bye.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry i misunderstood your question, I reformated the question to make my problem more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describing your mistakes can be complicated (and even a waste of time) for example `quality_label` is added to 3 layouts: `hblayout_labelcombo.addWidget(quality_label)`, `hblayout_labelmsslayout.addWidget(quality_label)` and `hblayout_mssbuttonlayout.addWidget(quality_label)` which is illogical.

So my answer focuses on implementing the solution, in this case it is enough to use a QGridLayout and establish the appropriate stretching factors.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class Widget(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.choose_a_label = qtw.QLabel(self.tr("Choose A"))
        self.choose_b_label = qtw.QLabel(self.tr("Choose B"))

        self.choose_a_combo = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.choose_a_combo.setFixedWidth(130)
        self.choose_b_combo = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.choose_b_combo.setFixedWidth(130)

        self.label_question = qtw.QLabel(self.tr("want to start msss ?"))
        self.button = qtw.QPushButton(self.tr("mss start"))

        lay = qtw.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.choose_a_label, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.choose_b_label, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.choose_a_combo, 1, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.choose_b_combo, 1, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label_question, 2, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, 3, 0)

        lay.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        lay.setRowStretch(4, 1)

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```